# C# - Unable to display image in picturebox

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

Working on a project that does (or will eventually do) the following:

- Access all images in a folder (for test phase using a folder in AppData called 'Test Images')
- Place them in a new folder, where the image name is used to place it in or create a sub-folder using an algorithm
- Save images in a 'List' so that when they have been saved, they can be displayed in a picturebox on the application - where they can be cycled through using prev/next buttons

The first two steps work fine, and I have checked that the images (only using two image files for the test phase) have been placed in subfolders.

I initialised an array of strings using the `Directory.GetAllFiles()` function in order to do this, meaning this array contains the paths of all the files that are being copied and manipulated. As a part of this process, I added each file path to the `List<Bitmap>` so they were able to be displayed in the picturebox.

However, whenever I try to run the function to display the image in the picturebox, the whole application crashes. No exception thrown or anything, just the whole thing stops working. I have no idea what is going on.

I've tried this using `picbox.Image =` to the element on the `List<Bitmap>` or using `picbox.ImageLocation =` to it's file path, but neither has been successful.
The code that should make this happen is shown below:

```
    public void saveLatestImages()
    {
        //specific path for My Pictures only
        string testImagesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Test Images";
        //if there is a Pictures folder
        if (Directory.Exists(testImagesPath))
        {   
            //get number of files in folder
            int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(testImagesPath).Count();

            //more than one file in folder
            if (fileCount > 0)
            {   
                //create data structures to store file info
                //filePaths holds path of each file represented as a string
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Test Images");

                //for each file in Pictures...
                for (int index = 0; index < fileCount; ++index)
                {
                    //get name of image at current index
                    imageName = filePaths[index];
                    //separate the part relating to the patient name (everything before (DD/MM/YYYY))
                    string subSpecifier = imageName.Split('\\').Last();
                    subSpecifier = subSpecifier.Split('_')[0];
                    //add to root directory to form subfolder name
                    subDirectory = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, subSpecifier);

                    //subdirectory name formulated, check for pre-existing
                    //subfolder does not exist
                    if(!Directory.Exists(subDirectory))
                    {
                        //create it
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectory);
                    }
                    //otherwise, file will be added to existing directory

                    //take everything from end and folder\file division to get unique filename
                    string fileName = imageName.Split('\\').Last();
                    //add this to the existing subDirectory
                    fileName = Path.Combine(subDirectory, fileName);

                    //copy the image into the subfolder using this unique filename
                    File.Copy(imageName, fileName, true); //true gives instruction to overwrite any existing file with the same path

                    //add full filename to list of bitmap images
                    images.Add(new Bitmap(fileName));

                    //update the shortcut to the file in the image storage shortcut folder
                    shortcutDirectory = getShortcut(subSpecifier, fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    public void displayLatestImages()
    {
        //there are images in list
        if (images.Count > 0)
        {
            //picbox defaults to first image
            picboxImage.ImageLocation = Path.GetFileName(images.First().ToString());
        }

        //check for images before or after current image to enable buttons
        checkFirstLast();
    }
```

This shows everything that saves the images to their new file location, and should then allow the first image added to the List to be displayed.

Any advice on how to correct this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: How many images are in your source folder? How large are they?

Comment: 2 Images in the source folder, as stated above. Both around 4MB, does this affect them being displayed? @TaW

Comment: No. Too many or too large Bitmaps can't be cached, but you surely didn't hit any limit.. Did you use the debugger to see how far the program gets?

Comment: Just stepped through it and found the code was getting caught in an infinite loop due to a while statement that has now been replaced with an if-else. Image now appears to load but then an error (red cross in a box) appears in the picture box instead. @TaW

Comment: The red cross means that the control can't be drawn for some reason. Maybe the images aren't loaded right.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll have a look into it! @TaW